# Сопоставление react POST запроса с контроллером asp.net core

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

Столкнулся с трудностью сопоставления запроса с клиентского приложения на react в контроллер asp.net core. При отправке формы приходит пустой аргумент, прошу подскажите как исправить и что почитать чтобы решить проблему
[image]

компонент регистрации react

```
export default function Register()
{
    const [register,setRegister] = useState(() =>{
        return {
            login: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            confrimPassword: ""
        }
    })

    const changeInputRegister = event => {
        event.persist();    //for async (learn more:https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/react-missing-event-persist)
        setRegister(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
            }
        })
    }

    const submitChackin = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!validator.isEmail(register.email)){
            alert("Email field is required!")
        }else if(register.password !== register.confrimPassword){
            alert("Passwords must ne identical!")
        }else if(!validator.isStrongPassword(register.password,{minSymbol: 0})){
            alert("Password must be more stronger :)")
        }else{
            axios.post('https://localhost:7019/account/register',{
                login: register.login,
                email: register.email,
                password: register.password
            }).then(res => {
                if(res.data === true) {
                    window.location.href = ''
                } else {
                    alert("User alredy exists!")
                }
            }).catch(() => {
                alert("Something went wrong....")
            })
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="form">
            <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit ={submitChackin}>
                <p><input
                type="login"
                id="login"
                name="login"
                placeholder="Enter login"
                value={register.login}
                onChange={changeInputRegister}
                /></p>
                <p><input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                value={register.email}
                onChange={changeInputRegister}
                /></p>
                <p><input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                value={register.password}
                onChange={changeInputRegister}
                /></p>
                <p><input
                type="password"
                id="confrimPassword"
                name="confrimPassword"
                placeholder="Confrim Password"
                value={register.confrimPassword}
                onChange={changeInputRegister}
                /></p>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил атрибут [FromBody] и все заработало)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом